# "Throttle" a queue of instructions using Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: ios, c, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I'm 99% sure something like this is possible with GCD, but I'm not too familiar with GCD and I'm not really sure how to properly ask the question, so here goes:

I'm trying to create a FIFO queue of instructions that are executed one at a time, with a delay X between the execution of each one. The instructions also need to be executed on the main thread. I assume I need to create a serial queue and `dispatch_async` each instruction with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the delay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to use dispatch_get_main_queue().  You should create your own serial queue for your own needs rather than using the main queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myapp.description", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Given that you are reading instructions from a FIFO, I suggest you use dispatch I/O using something like:

```
int fd = open(...);

dispatch_io_handler_t stream_handler = ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
   ...
}

void (^stream_cleanup_handler)(int error) = ^(int error) {
    close(fd);
};

dispatch_io_t stream = dispatch_io_create(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, fd, my_queue, stream_cleanup_handler);

dispatch_io_read(stream, 0, SIZE_MAX, my_queue, stream_handler);
```